# TypeScript + React: Avoid setState on unmounted components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know that a common pattern of avoiding calling `.setState()` on an unmounted component is by adding a private property such as `_isMounted` to keep track of it, as mentioned in a [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

I've been using this method like this:

```
class Hello extends React.PureComponent{
_isMounted = false;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // ...
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}
// ...
}
```

Everything was fine until I started to use TypeScript. I tried to do this in the same way:

```
class Hello extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
private _isMounted: boolean;

constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // ...
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}
}
```

But then it always throws a type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property _isMounted of #<Component> which has only a getter
```

For now, the only solution I know is to explicitly write a setter for it. But I don't really understand if this is the expected way to do it. Doesn't TypeScript generate getter and setter automatically?

Updated:
A codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/l59wnqy5zz

Comment: I think the problem must be in code you haven't shown. In the `Hello` class shown, `_isMounted` is clearly a data property, not an accessor property.

Comment: The [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Hello%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_isMounted%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20componentDidMount()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._isMounted%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20componentWillUnmount()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._isMounted%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) is happy with it (removed the React-isms, which shouldn't matter).

Comment: I think _isMounted is a private property of React.Component. Rename it and it should work.

Comment: or better yet, teardown any async stuff when unmount happens. eg if you have `setTimeout` / `Interval`, keep a reference and call `clearTimeout`. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @Stramski Yes it did work when I change the name! Thanks! But why didn't the private property we define here overwrite the one from React.Component?

Comment: You are just declaring the property there. The typecheck is still added inside React.Component. Declaring a setter should work too.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow it's the name, to me `_isMounted` actually works but not `isMounted`.

> @Stramski points out, I think _isMounted is a private property of React.Component. Rename it and it should work.

To confirm, I rename the variable to `mounted`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful for other developers 
**Using getters and setters**

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    private isFullyMounted: boolean = false;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.isMounted = true;
    }

    public componentWillUnmount() {
        this.isMounted = false;
    }

    public set isMounted(status: boolean) {
        this.isFullyMounted = status;
    }

    public get isMounted() {
        return this.isFullyMounted;
    }
}
```